GPS Distance calculate with noises
I have points array but there is some noises like this;

But the real direction is;

When i calculate all points with haversine formula i am getting wrong distance because noises took like %20-%30 more distance. I want to extract all noises from my main data or calculate distance with minimum tolerance. Is there any algorithm about it? I found kalman filter and i used a library for it.But its drop only %2-%3 tolerance. So i need more usefull algorithm to extract those noises from my main data.
You can check the temp data from this link.
Calculate code;
const moment = require("moment");
const locations = require("./mock_data.json");

function calcKiloMeterDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  const r = 6371; // km
  const p = Math.PI / 180;
  const a =
    0.5 -
    Math.cos((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
    (Math.cos(lat1 * p) *
      Math.cos(lat2 * p) *
      (1 - Math.cos((lon2 - lon1) * p))) /
      2;

  return 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
}
const calcAllRows = () => {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
    const point1 = locations[i - 1];
    const point2 = locations[i];
    const time = point2.lastLocationUpdatedAt - point1.lastLocationUpdatedAt;
    const km = calcKiloMeterDistance(
      point1.latitude,
      point1.longitude,
      point2.latitude,
      point2.longitude
    );
    // const speed = (km / time) * 3600; //Km/sa
    // console.log(
    //   moment.unix(point2.lastLocationUpdatedAt).format("HH:mm:ss"),
    //   time,
    //   (km / time) * 3600
    // );
    total += km;
  }
  console.log(total);
};
calcAllRows();




It is difficult to say what will best "clean up" your data points, but something like a Moving Average Filter might do the trick, if the noise is evenly distributed around where the actual data point should be.

I tried that but it is not well for me. Because you know vehicle can turn from road so moving average will effect to lose my correct data. But thanks for advice.
